# Problema com câmera android/java

Tags: java, android

Ao abrir a Câmera ou tentar pegar foto do álbum a intent que chama essas funções se encerra,
eu chamo com:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                     File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                     intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                     startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

e se eu voltar a Activity não está mais lá e como consequência não funciona o onActivityResult(). Detalhe no android 2.3 funciona e esse erro acontece no 4.4.2.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gmail.permission.READ_GMAIL" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.NovaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nova"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.FormBuscaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nova"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.SearchActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nova"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.SingleActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nova"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.SingleActivityEdit"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nova"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.ListaTrabalhosActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_lista_trabalhos"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.NovaOsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nova_os"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.FechaLoteActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fechar_lote"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.DefinicoesActivity"
        android:label="@string/definicoes"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.mgoficina.ExportaService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MGO_INICIAR_EXPORTACAO" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.mgoficina.FechaLoteService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MGO_FECHAR_LOTE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.mgoficina.BackupService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MGO_RESPOSTA" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.UserActivity"
        android:label="@string/dados_usuario"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.RecuperaDadosActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_recupera_dados"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.PerfilActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.mgoficina.DeletaService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MGO_DELETA" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.BemVindoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.SobreActivity"
        android:label="@string/sobre"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.ClientesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_clientes"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.CameraActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_camera" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Por favor uma luz.

Comment: Como está seu `AndroidManifest`?

Comment: Ok @Wakim, editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido essa dúvida!
Eu desabilitei a "Opções do desenvolvedor" nas configurações do android 4.4.2 e funcionou direitinho. Por quê dá erro; não sei.